# Windows, @font-face and Cyrillic

Tags: html, css, windows, font-face, webfonts

I'm having a problem with font-face and Cyrillic characters. When displayed in any browser on OS X the fonts render properly, but when viewed on a Windows 7 machine (chrome, ie etc), the fonts fail to render.

The fonts have been put through Font Squirrel and the demo that comes with the files also fails.

The font-face css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansregular';
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Heres a really basic example of my problem. http://joshmahony.com/font_test/opensans-regular-demo.html

Edit: I've updated my link so fonts fallback to times new roman and added some english characters to show that the Cyrillic is falling back.

Comment: It renders for me, and btw OS has nothing to do in this, it's just the browser versions

Comment: It also translated for me, it says **Dmitry Khlebnikov led practice 2012 "Organizational development and human potential"**

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I've realised that my Windows version of Chrome is just defaulting to its standard font. So you guys are running Windows and it is rendering in the Open Sans Regular font?

Comment: Also I've noticed, on OS X any Cyrillic characters are falling back to default, where as english characters and numbers are rendering properly, is that what you are seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably generated a version of Open Sans that does not contain Cyrillic characters. Using Google Web Fonts pages, you need to check the relevant checkbox(es) in the user interface. For Russian, I suppose checking “Cyrillic” is enough, “Cyrillic Extended” is not needed.

The choice is to be made on the “Almost done” page, under “2. Choose the character sets you want”.

Comment: I'm going to give this ago now, I've updated my link so fonts fallback to times new roman and added some english characters to show the difference.

Comment: Thank you Jukka! I'm now using the Google Font API version rather than hosting it myself and it seems to work perfectly. Solved!